# Custom While in json array

Tags: php, json, while-loop

Its My PHP Code:

```
$res_media=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mv_media");
$media = array();
while($resualt_media = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_media)) {
    $media[]= $resualt_media['title'];
}
echo $media;
```

And Its My output:

```
["Test","Test","Test","Test","Test"]
```

I want Change it to this format :

```
["Test"],["Test"],["Test"],["Test"],["Test"]
```

I changed My Code to this code :

```
$res_media=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mv_media");
$media = array();
    while($resualt_media = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_media)) {
    $media[]= [$resualt_media['title']];
}
echo $media;
```

Now My OutPut :

```
[["Test","Test","Test","Test","Test"]]
```

But I need This custom output:

```
[["Test"],["Test"],["Test"],["Test"],["Test"],["ItsMyCustomChild"]]
```

I want add Custom Child with out database!

Comment: please use mysqli or PDO instead for database connection. Your code won't work when you switch to 7.0 or newer

Comment: I know but it ok and don't worry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `$media[] = [<value>]` to `$media[][] = <value>` and it will work, because then you'll create a new array inside an array.

Comment: how create new array inside and array can you help me?

Comment: how can i add custom field to my $media after while process?

Comment: Just like you do in the while loop, but just out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this approach:

```
<?php
$input = json_decode('["Test","Test","Test","Test","Test"]');
$output = [];

array_walk($input, function($element) use (&$output) {
    $output[] = [$element];
});

var_dump(json_encode($output));
```

Alternatively this can be simplified to just:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode('["Test","Test","Test","Test","Test"]');

array_walk($data, function(&$element) {
    $element = [$element];
});

var_dump(json_encode($data));
```

The created array structure obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test
        )
)
```

Which, if you again `json_encode()` it, results in the desired format:

```
string(46) "[["Test"],["Test"],["Test"],["Test"],["Test"]]"
```

The specific issue you are actually dealing with is not so much the creation of the desired structure, but that you are trying to modify the JSON string instead of the actual array you want to work with. That is why a call to `json_decode()` is used initially.

Answer (score 0):

```
$res_media=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mv_media");
$media = array();
    while($resualt_media = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_media)) {
   array_push($media,array($resualt_media['title']));
}
print_r $media;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change below line. and you will get your desired result.

```
$media[][]= $resualt_media['title'];
```

if you want to see what you get . you need to add json_encode() after the while.
like below

```
echo json_encode($media);
```